# squirell mail failed to aurocreate mailbox

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, squirrelmail

May I begin with saying I am very beginner with this issue, and have been searching for hours to try and fix this.

I am trying to setup a mailserver using Squirrel Mail, Docevot and Postfix.

I have gotten to the point where I can get to the squirrel mail login, but I keep getting this error...

Dec 19 16:24:59 vps647603 dovecot: imap(sales): Error: open(/var/mail/sales) failed: Permission denied (euid=1005(sales) egid=1005(sales) missing +w perm: /var/mail, we're not in group 8(mail), dir owned by 0:8 mode=0775)
Dec 19 16:24:59 vps647603 dovecot: imap(sales): Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox INBOX: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2019-12-19 16:24:59]

The results of 'postconf -n' and 'dovecot -n' are below if this helps..

---

root@vps647603:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mattemedia.co.uk, vps647603.ovh.net, localhost.ovh.net, localhost
myhostname = vps647603.ovh.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes

---

root@vps647603:~# dovecot -n

## 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

## OS: Linux 3.13.0-167-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS

mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap pop3"
ssl_cert =

Any help would be extremely appreciated, and may I apologise in advance for my lack of knowledge.

Many thanks

Comment: Running a web server is easy; running a mail server is not. If the reason of your exercise should be not to learn about how to operate such a thing and instead is to have a system ready for you in production use, then you are far better suited with a specialized setup like Mailcow (https://mailcow.email), which comes preconfigured with all the internal bells and whistles. Also note that Squirrel Mail is horribly outdated, and unmaintained. You should try Roundcube or Horde Webmail instead.

Answer (score 0):

Dovecot is lacking write permissions in directory `/var/mail/sales` and the error message is thus quite clear.

This command will add the user to the 'mail' group:

```
adduser sales mail
```